# Where to place ''recently'' in a sentence?

Tags: grammar, adverbs, sentence

I believe both of the following placings of the word ''recently'' is correct, but how can I be sure that it is 100% correct without having to think whether it's correct:

> 1. I **recently** bought the exact same car.
> 2. I bought the exact same car **recently**.

Are there any rules for the placing?

Comment: There are no rules.  You can use either sentence, and you could even use "Recently, I bought the exact same car"

Comment: You probably don't mean "the exact same car", but "the exact same model".  If it were "the exact same car", then you've presumably already sold it to someone else, else why you you be remarking on it: you would say "That's MY car!".

Comment: @TrevorD haha you're correct.

Answer (score -2):

I'd go with "I recently bought the same car". I think "exact" is superfluous here. "Exact" basically means "same". Back to your specific question, "I recently bought the [exact] same car" reads better to me.

Comment: but the second one isn't necessarily wrong right?

Comment: Sorry Milo, I didn't check back for a response till now. No, I think it looks ok to me too.

Comment: "I think "exact" is superfluous here." Not necessarily. It can make the difference between e.g. having bought the same brand/model of car, and having bought the same brand/model/color. "Exact" merely stresses how incredibly similar the two cars are (= more than you would expect)

Answer (score -2):

I have recently bought the exact same car.

Use of "-ly" words in the sentence should be made along with the subject. Here, the subject is "Me" and the word recently is placed right after the words "I have..."